# Getting an Element of a Particular Class

Tags: jquery, html

Is it possible to get an element with a particular class solely by using the class name? For example, if I have:

```
<div class="hello"> Hello World! </div>
```

Is there a method in jQuery that accepts a parameter `hello` and returns the div(s) that have class "hello"?

I know that I can use a for loop until I find a given div with the class/id-name, but I was just curious if there was anything else.

Comment: I want to flag this as a duplicate of something but looking around indicates this actually may be a case where the question is so basic that genuinely nobody has ever asked it before, hah.

Comment: That said, does anyone want to defend their downvotes? It may be an obvious answer to most of us, but the OP asked a question that they genuinely appear to not know the answer to, and included everything they (maybe incorrectly) believe to be possible to solve it. It's got good grammar and formatting. It's more than a lot of questions that slip by can say for themselves.

Comment: But, also, how is it possible to have heard of jQuery the library but not jQuery the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".hello")
```

The JQuery class selector will select everything with the class "hello".

http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the class selector `.`

```
$("div.hello") //Div's with class of hello
```

Or

```
$(".hello") //All elements with class of hello
```

Answer (score 0):

I give you an answer, under the condition, that you show me the for loop you could use, because I have no idea how that would work. Also interesting: How is "select an element by it's class" not the very first thing you learned with jQuery? What can you even do without that?

Anyway:

```
$(".hello");
```

Selects everything of class "hello".

Comment: 'Twas a very stupid question which I realized my idiocy immediately after I had posted it.

i was originally planning on using a for-loop to go through each list element in a ul, using hasClass() to check if it has a given class, and then assigning it to a var and breaking out of the loop from there (oddly enough I didn't think to just use selectors, even for elements that have more than one class).

Comment: Ha, well, alright. Funny idea though. I'll remeber that as a good "How to not jQuery"-punchline if you don't mind. ;)

Comment: Of course ;). It's weird too, because I would consider myself fairly competent with jQuery, as I use it fairly often. My guess is I was a bit too tired when writing this question, thus overthinking the problem which is otherwise normally very easy :O. Oh well, lesson learned I guess lol

Answer (score 0):

Since everyone's just throwing out the jQuery solution to the question, it's worth noting that selecting elements is one of the most basic JavaScript concepts so it's absolutely possible to do it without jQuery as well. You'd use the JavaScript `document.getElementsByClassName` function, which is well documented [at the Mozilla Developer Network.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName)